# dpkg: error processing ttf-droid (--remove)

Tags: 10.10, package-management, dpkg

I have been installing various applications on my Ubuntu 10.10 laptop and I've been noticing a common theme. There is always an error in the terminal at the end of the install and it is as follows:

```
Removing ttf-droid ...
/etc/defoma/hints/ttf-droid.hints: Unable to open, or empty.
dpkg: error processing ttf-droid (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ttf-droid
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

try this command:

`cd /var/lib/dpkg && sudo mv info info.bak && sudo mkdir info`

and reinstallation 
I have the same problem,but I already to get ubuntu's breath back .
http://apps.hi.baidu.com/share/detail/8446391